# How can I make quicklook loop previewed videos?

Tags: macos, video, finder, quicklook

When I use Quick Look in the Finder to preview an mp4 I would prefer if the videos looped over and over instead of stopping at the end, because the play back button is really tiny and hard to click. Pressing space twice again works but is terribly jarring. Is there a setting to change the playback behaviour?

Comment: Just use the spacebar twice as you mentioned. There might be a setting  or flag you could tweak in the Terminal. I don't know of one.

Answer (score 1):

Use this flag in terminal, its works with Quicktime app or when selecting multiple video files in Finder

defaults write com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX MGPlayMovieOnOpen 1

to disable replace 1 with 0

Answer (score 0):

> defaults write com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX MGPlayMovieOnOpen 1

This doesn't loop video, it will automatically show subtitles and closed captioning on open.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2197326?tstart=0

Comment: An answer with the same suggestion is already posted which means this post is duplicating information. Also refer to [why some answers are deleted\(http://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers)